# 90's YA novel: Youth leaves village against village taboos

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

I'm trying to find the name of a book I read in the early-to-mid '90's, from my school's library (in Canada, should that help). I'm pretty sure it was a young adult novel.

From what I can remember, it involved a youth (I think a boy) becoming disillusioned with his primitive village and its superstitious people, and setting out on a journey, beyond the boundaries of his village (which were marked by metal stakes with coloured stripes or ribbons) into the wilderness beyond. He eventually discovers a cave, which turns out to be a man-made structure.

Here is a list of points I remember:

- Rural village, superstitious/fearful elders imposing many taboos on the people, including one against leaving.
- Our protagonist, a young man (or woman) leaves village against elders' wishes, and it is implied that he wouldn't be welcome to return again.
- The village boundary is marked with a metal pole (which is unusual as the villagers don't have metal of it's quality) with a coloured ribbon or stripe on it.
- I have vague memory of the character fighting his way upstream along a cliffside during his journey.

Comment: I immediately thought of Monica Hughes, a Canadian young-adult science fiction author, but I haven't been able to trace this back to any of her books.

Comment: Was it [The Guardian of Isis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Guardian_of_Isis)?  Matches the "taboo" reference and much of the plot anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty sure that's it, although I seem to be misremembering a lot of the details judging by the Wiki synopsis. I definitely recognise the cover though. Now all I have to do is find a copy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I've finished reading [*The Keeper of the Isis Light*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Keeper_of_the_Isis_Light) and [*The Guardian of Isis*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1190264.The_Guardian_of_Isis) by Monica Hughes, and they immediately came back to me as I was reading them. While a lot of information was misremembered, I can confidently say that this series (particularly The Guardian of Isis, as it is the one with the dystopian setting) is what I was looking for.

Thanks to Pixel and Trenin for pointing me in the right direction.