# Fantasy books in which science is outlawed while the characters search for sites from the past

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading a series of books in which science is outlawed. The main character and a small group are looking for sites which include a pre nuclear war silo or bunker complex with hi-tech defences.

Comment: Is this the story where the MacGuffin is an orbital space-plane and launcher stored in a secret underground base?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Or is it the one where the spirit aiding the protagonists is symbolized by an elephant?

Comment: James Gunn's "The Burning" and Norman Spinrad's "Song from the Stars" both had this general theme, but neither was part of a series.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be Monica Hughes's *[Isis](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/703359.The_Isis_Trilogy)* series? The second book, [*The Guardian of Isis*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1190264.The_Guardian_of_Isis), follows a young boy in a society where technology is banned, seeking a silo.

[image: Cover of *The Guardian of Isis*]

> Years have passed on Isis, but life has gone backward, not forward. Under their leader, Mark London, the settlers have abandoned the technological knowledge of their forefathers. Upper Isis is now a forbidden zone, and the history of the first inhabitants from Earth has been replaced by myth. But one inquiring young man yearns to know the truth, and soon he gets the chance to find it.

I thought I remembered this one coming up here before, so I searched the site for *[story-identification] silo*, which led me to [90's YA novel: Youth leaves village against village taboos, discovers missile silo and that the world is post-apocalypse](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151028/90s-ya-novel-youth-leaves-village-against-village-taboos-discovers-missile-si)

Comment: If this is the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: Wow, not only have I never seen that cover (which isn't that strange, obviously) but even [*ISFDb doesn't know it*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?17445)!

Comment: ^_^ I just grabbed the first one Goodreads showed.