Future primitive society. Tribespeople find a rocket labelled USA. Protagonist's young child brother is important to plot twist
I read this short story online, maybe in an online magazine, about 2020. The magazine artwork looked very professional.I think there was an orange drawing of the rocket. SF Magazines I remember reading at the time are F&SF,Asimovs and Clarkesworld. At the time I had a Kindle Unlimited subscription. It might be one of the magazines that can be read free with Kindle Unlimited.
The protagonist is about 16 years old and is the most skilled hunter in his tribe. He cares for his young brother who is about 5 years old. The whole tribe, all live in one ancient building. The children of the tribe are taught the alphabet but have new names for the letters based on the shapes of them and their sounds. ABC is arrowhead, breasts, cup.
The protagonist and his little brother sleep in a certain part of the building. A woman is obviously attracted to him and wants to come sleep in the same place, she says there is plenty of room. He says there is only room for him and his brother.
Their mother has been dead for some time. The small child manages somehow to keep himself fastidiously clean, though nobody else can as their environment is filthy.
There is a character who seems to be an elderly shaman who talks with the protagonist and his brother. He gives them advice.
At one point in the story they find a rocket in a pool or lake. They have no idea what it is but say the names for the letters on it, obviously USA. The name for the letter S was snake. So they said - word beginning with U-,Snake,Arrowhead.(Maybe U was upside down cup or upside down something.)
The plot twist is...

 His little brother died years ago. He has been carrying around a pouch of his bones and imagining the child is alive and speaking with him. Some others humour him and pretend to also see and hear his living brother.


Probably not the answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/230688/80s-90s-ya-novel-child-named-gen-finds-dragons-which-are-actually-icbms

@FuzzyBoots I checked and indeed they are describing a different work.
